# Why vectors outperform lists when number of elements is small?

Tags: c++, vector, linked-list

In his book The C++ Programming Language (4th Edition), Bjarne Stroustrup states that:

> Please note that a `vector` is usually (surprisingly, unless you
>   understand machine architecture) more efficient than a `list` for
>   short sequences of small elements (even for `insert()` and `erase()`).

He doesn't elaborate on that any further, so I'd like to know why it is true and roughly how short those sequences have to be (i.e., the number of elements)?

Comment: See Herb Sutter's talk: [Modern C++: What You Need to Know](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-661). It actually addresses exactly how short they have to be. FWIW, here's one slide: http://i.imgur.com/XRvjKpi.png

Comment: It's a bit like saying "What's faster, O(1) or O(n)". Someone says "obviously O(1)" but then you respond "Aha, the O(1) algorithm takes 30 seconds for all input sizes, but the O(n) algorithm takes `4n` seconds, and we only have 5 items this time".  The exact details will depend on the implementation.

Comment: `insert` and `erase` that aren't at the end of the `vector` are the worst-case operations. But if the size of the vector is small, even those can be performed without too much work. The efficiency of simple operations coupled with cache coherency make them faster than you'd think.

Answer (score 1):

> ... and roughly how short those sequences have to be

The correct answer is: you have to measure.

It depends on what you're storing in the container, how expensive that type is to construct, copy and move, it's size, and your access and insertion patterns.

It will also vary between machines, and possibly compilers.

---

To answer the first part of your question:

> ... so I'd like to know why it is true ...

The reason it's true, in the cases where it is, is that a vector's contiguous and minimally-padded memory layout co-operates much better with modern CPUs' cache subsystems than a list's does.

- `vector`

  - your loop is probably something like

    ```
    for (size_t i=0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    ```

    where `v.size()` can often be called only once, and both that and `i` will fit in registers. Branch prediction can do a good job of allowing several consecutive iterations to run interleaved if other dependencies allow, keeping the instruction pipeline full
  - your next access (`v[i+1]`) is probably in cache already, so is very fast. It's either in the same cache line as `v[i]`, or the next one, and sequential reads are relatively easy to pre-fetch
  - however many of your values fit in a cache line, that's how many you get per cache line. There's no (unnecessary) padding between, so no unnecessary cache misses
- `list`

  - your loop is probably something like

    ```
    for (list::const_iterator i=l.begin(); i != l.end(); ++i) {
    ```

    where each consecutive value for `i` has to be loaded from memory (via a pointer from the previous node)
  - your next access (`*++i`) *may* be in cache already, but:
  - however many of your values fit in a cache line, fewer list nodes will fit: there's an overhead of at least two pointers (one in a singly-linked list). If your value is the same size as a pointer (we were talking about small values), you get one third as many in a cache line using a list, giving three times more cache misses.
  - note also that speculative execution of the next iteration depends on loading a value rather than incrementing a register: a cache miss here is not only slower in itself, but also stalls speculative execution

Answer (score 0):

I assume that it's because a list uses a dynamic approach to extending a list (possibly pointers to the next so that you can easily insert at a particular place without having to rearrange memory). Whereas vectors are actually a simple array with some nice sugarcoating to make it easier to use (with optional exceptions for boundary issues, if you use the right functions).

Basically, when you instantiate a vector, it allocates a small array of type T. When you push a new item at the end, it just writes the value into the already allocated space, if you haven't already grown too large. However, when you add to a list, it has to allocate memory and store that location inside the various pointers (I'm guessing here, but that's how linked lists work). If you know how large a vector will be (or can guess reasonably well), it is very efficient. However, once you exceed it's underlying array's size, it has to reallocate the memory for the newly enlarged data structure and then copy everything over. That is very expensive for growing vectors to large sizes. Off the top of my head, vectors grow exponentially, so the number of faults decreases after several failures, but it's still very expensive.

Comment: You assume a vector is faster because a list doesn't have to rearrange memory?